# Curl keeps saying "SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure" but it should be TLS

Tags: ssl, curl, https, libcurl, tls1.2

The PHP version on my webserver was recently updated. Now I notice that when downloading external https URLs with Curl, for *one specific* server it fails, giving me this error:

`SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

Downloading https stuff from this server though Curl worked fine before.

Now the strange this is: it seems an SSL3 error, but as I understood from other cases regarding this error (also here on SO) it's due to SSL3 no longer being supported by updated versions of PHP or Curl. And rightly so, since SSL3 is insecure.

However, this particular webserver uses TLS1.2, and by no means SSL3.

So if my Curl is not using SSL3, and neither is the webserver, why am I still getting SSL3 related errors?

I already tried setting `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` to 4, 5 or 6, and setting `CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST` to `TLSv1`, all to no avail, error keeps coming up.

Comment: What doest http://ssllabs.com/ssltest/ says about that server?

Comment: @Tom it says only TLS1.2 on the server, no older TLS or SSL versions ([results](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=btc.blockr.io))

Answer (score 0):

Although this error message looks like it is using SSL 3.0 it is probably not. Since TLS1.0 is practically SSL3.1 etc you will find lots of functions and error messages having the SSLv3 string within the TLS code path in OpenSSL. The problem with this specific server is probably something else and one would need to know the server hostname and your installed version of OpenSSL to find out more about the problem.

EDIT: Based on the comment the version of OpenSSL used with curl is 0.9.8b. Since the server can only do TLS 1.2 the handshake will fail, since TLS 1.2 is only supported since OpenSSL 1.0.1. Apart from that 0.9.8b is years out of support and has several security problems which got fixed in later versions.

Comment: In phpinfo, under Curl, it says: `cURL Information` is `7.15.5` and `SSL Version` is `OpenSSL/0.9.8b`. Under OpenSSL it says `OpenSSL Library Version` and `OpenSSL Header Version` are both `OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008`. Obviously these haven't been updated for a long while, will ask the hosting provider to do so (I have no control over this myself).

Comment: @RocketNuts: see edited response - the software you use is simple way too old to access the server.

Comment: Thanks @Steffen, yes I was actually surprised to find out about this ancient OpenSSL. I somehow assumed it would have been fairly up to date along with the recent PHP upgrade, but apparently not. I hope they'll soon be able to update OpenSSL as well.